# Linq: ForEach looks like different behavior

Tags: c#, linq

I am having problems in Linq.

I have next class:

```
public class product {
  public int nserie {get; set;}
  public bool seleccionado {get; set;}
}
```

I have a List of products, and i have one column with the input check box (which will set value depending of seleccionado) and column nserie.

When I check the button in header check all, I am doing this loop:

```
pedidos.ForEach(x => { if (x.NSerie == nserie) { x.seleccionado = true; } });
```

Looks like it is not working, behavior of loop if strange.

What is wrong?

EXPECTED THIS:

```
 public static int MarcarCheckBox(string nserie, bool valor) 
 {
    ...
    foreach (TarjetaActivar pedido in pedidos) 
    {
        if (nserie == "") pedido.seleccionado = true;
        else pedido.seleccionado = valor;
    }
    ...
 }
```

valor is a boolean.

Comment: what is the expected behaviour and what is the current one ?

Comment: Please clarify what *'it is not working'* and *'behavior is strange'* means

Comment: You don't use `valor` in your `ForEach` operator. Why do you expect it will appear? Your actual code and expected code are completely different. Condition is different, no *else* part, not *valor*.

Comment: I added expected code in the question with a traditional loop what I wanted in Linq

Comment: If you want to achieve what your `foreach` loop is doing, why are you putting completely different code in the `ForEach` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplified:

```
pedidos.ForEach(p => p.seleccionado = (nserie == "" || valor))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing your else clause in the linq foreach. Try it like this:

```
  pedidos.ForEach(x => { if (x.nserie == "") { x.seleccionado = true; } else {x.seleccionado = valor } });
```